# Finding the means of the three classes the data have been assigned to in LDA

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, linear-discriminant

I am looking at example code for how to calculate Fisher’s LDA, which is based on Q = W^{-1}B.

The data is imported as follows:

```
aircraft = read_csv(file = "aircraft.csv") %>%
  mutate( Period = factor( Period ))
```

I have the following example for Fisher's LDA. Q is calculated using `solve(W, B)`, and then the first eigenvector of Q is found, and then the assigned classes:

```
W1 = cov( dplyr::select( dplyr::filter( aircraft, Period == 1 ), -Year, -Period ) )
W2 = cov( dplyr::select( dplyr::filter( aircraft, Period == 2 ), -Year, -Period ) )
W3 = cov( dplyr::select( dplyr::filter( aircraft, Period == 3 ), -Year, -Period ) )

W = W1 + W2 + W3

mu1 = colMeans( dplyr::select( dplyr::filter( aircraft, Period == 1 ), -Year, -Period ) ) 
mu2 = colMeans( dplyr::select( dplyr::filter( aircraft, Period == 2 ), -Year, -Period ) ) 
mu3 = colMeans( dplyr::select( dplyr::filter( aircraft, Period == 3 ), -Year, -Period ) )  
mu = rbind( mu1, mu2, mu3 )

B = ( 3 - 1 ) * cov (mu ) 

Q = solve( W, B )

eta = eigen( Q )$vectors[,1]

XX = dplyr::select( aircraft, -Year, -Period ) 

XXproj = as.matrix( XX ) %*% as.matrix( eta ) 
muP1 = t( as.matrix( mu1 ) ) %*% as.matrix( eta )
muP2 = t( as.matrix( mu2 ) ) %*% as.matrix( eta )
muP3 = t( as.matrix( mu3 ) ) %*% as.matrix( eta )

tXXproj = t( XXproj ) 
m1 = as.data.frame( tXXproj )  - muP1 
m2 = as.data.frame( tXXproj )  - muP2
m3 = as.data.frame( tXXproj )  - muP3
mm = rbind( abs( m1 ), abs( m2 ), abs( m3 ) ) 
classes = sapply( mm, which.min ) 

classified = data.frame( assigned = classes, aircraft )

xtabs( ~ assigned + Period , data = classified )
```

The command `str(classified)` results in the following output:

```
'data.frame':   709 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ assigned: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Year    : int  14 14 14 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 ...
 $ Period  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Power   : num  82 82 224 164 119 ...
 $ Span    : num  12.8 11 17.9 14.5 12.9 ...
 $ Length  : num  7.6 9 10.3 9.8 7.9 ...
 $ Weight  : num  1070 830 2200 1946 1190 ...
 $ Speed   : int  105 145 135 138 140 177 113 230 175 106 ...
 $ Range   : int  400 402 500 500 400 350 402 700 525 300 ...
```

I want to find the means of the three classes the data have been assigned to. This sounds like it should be simple; however, I'm inexperienced with R and unsure of how to do this. I'm thinking that the `apply` and `select` functions are relevant for this situation, but I'm unsure.

I was able to implement my own LDA using the relevant R function:

```
lda.0 = lda( Period ~ Power + Span + Length + Weight + Speed + Range, data = aircraft )
preds.0 = predict( lda.0 )$class
xtabs( ~ preds.0 + aircraft$Period )
```

And I want to do the same (find the means of the three classes) with my implementation as with the above example.

The command `str(predict( lda.0 ))` results in the following output:

```
List of 3
 $ class    : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ posterior: num [1:709, 1:3] 0.712 0.659 0.67 0.665 0.69 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:709] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
 $ x        : num [1:709, 1:2] -1.469 -0.988 -1.504 -1.22 -1.385 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:709] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "LD1" "LD2"
```

So what is a good way to find the means of the three classes the data have been assigned to for these two cases?

The full dataset is too large to include in this post, so I have included a smaller version of the dataset:

```
structure(list(Year = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L), Period = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Power = c(82, 82, 223.6, 
164, 119, 74.5, 74.5, 279.5, 82, 67, 112, 149, 119, 119, 238.5, 
205, 82, 119, 194, 336, 558.9, 287, 388, 164, 194, 194, 186.3, 
119, 119, 89.4, 126.7, 149, 119, 536.6, 402, 298, 298, 342.8, 
536, 223.6, 521.6, 186.3, 238.5, 287, 335.3, 335.3, 335.3, 335.3, 
335.3, 335.3, 357.7, 313, 782.6, 298, 670.6, 223.5, 335.3, 391, 
391, 436, 391, 436, 171.4, 350, 298, 223.6, 298, 634, 223.5, 
864.4, 760, 503.5, 63.3, 357.7, 812, 335.3, 298, 298, 335.3, 
298, 317, 231, 335.3, 432, 918, 745.2, 424.8, 372.6, 782, 626, 
544, 335.3, 372.6, 373, 391.2, 864, 894, 179, 74.5, 391.2), Span = c(12.8, 
11, 17.9, 14.5, 12.9, 7.5, 11.13, 14.3, 7.8, 11, 11.7, 12.8, 
8.5, 13.3, 14.9, 12, 9.4, 15.95, 16.74, 22.2, 23.4, 14.3, 23.72, 
11.9, 14.4, 14.4, 9.7, 8, 9.4, 14.55, 9.1, 8.11, 9.5, 20.73, 
22.8, 38.4, 14, 26.5, 30.48, 9.7, 15.5, 9.1, 14.17, 10.1, 14.8, 
15.62, 14.05, 14.05, 14.8, 15.24, 14, 12.24, 27.2, 8.84, 22.86, 
7.7, 9.5, 9.8, 15.93, 15.93, 15.93, 15.93, 13.08, 15.21, 8.94, 
9.6, 10.8, 13.72, 8.9, 26.72, 25, 9.6, 8.84, 11.58, 17.3, 12.5, 
12.1, 12.09, 9.8, 15.3, 9.08, 17.75, 15.3, 15.15, 27.4, 22, 13.7, 
10.3, 22.76, 22.25, 17.25, 11, 12, 9.5, 14.15, 20.4, 20.4, 14.5, 
8.84, 11.35), Length = c(7.6, 9, 10.35, 9.8, 7.9, 6.3, 8.28, 
9.4, 6.7, 8.3, 8, 8.7, 7.4, 9.6, 8.9, 7.9, 6.2, 10.25, 10.77, 
10.9, 12.6, 9.4, 11.86, 9.8, 9.2, 8.9, 8, 6.5, 6.95, 9.83, 7.3, 
6.38, 8.5, 13.27, 13.5, 20.85, 9.2, 14.33, 19.16, 6.5, 9.7, 8.1, 
9.68, 7.7, 10.8, 11.89, 10.97, 11.28, 9.5, 11.42, 11, 7.3, 18.2, 
7.01, 18.08, 6.8, 6.8, 7.1, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 9.27, 9.78, 
6.17, 6.4, 7.32, 10.74, 6.9, 18.97, 15.1, 7.06, 7.17, 9.5, 10.55, 
8.38, 8.7, 8.81, 6.7, 9.42, 5.99, 10.27, 10.22, 11, 19.8, 14.63, 
11.2, 6.56, 14.88, 13.81, 12.6, 7, 7.5, 7.2, 9.91, 14.8, 15, 
9.8, 7.17, 8.94), Weight = c(1070, 830, 2200, 1946, 1190, 653, 
930, 1575, 676, 920, 1353, 1550, 888, 1275, 1537, 1292, 611, 
1350, 1700, 3312, 4920, 1510, 3625, 900, 1665, 1640, 1081, 625, 
932, 1378, 886, 902, 1070, 5670, 3636, 12925, 2107, 4770, 6060, 
1192, 1900, 1050, 2155, 1379, 2858, 3380, 2290, 2290, 2347, 3308, 
2630, 1333, 10000, 1351, 6250, 885, 1531, 1438, 3820, 3820, 3820, 
3820, 1905, 2646, 1151, 1266, 1575, 2383, 860, 7983, 6200, 1484, 
567, 1867, 4350, 1935, 1823, 2253, 1487, 2220, 1244, 2700, 2280, 
3652, 8165, 5500, 3568, 1414, 5875, 5460, 4310, 1500, 1795, 1628, 
2449, 6900, 6900, 1900, 567, 2102), Speed = c(105L, 145L, 135L, 
138L, 140L, 177L, 113L, 230L, 175L, 106L, 140L, 170L, 175L, 157L, 
183L, 201L, 209L, 145L, 120L, 135L, 152L, 176L, 140L, 190L, 175L, 
175L, 205L, 196L, 165L, 146L, 175L, 222L, 159L, 166L, 158L, 146L, 
185L, 120L, 157L, 226L, 205L, 230L, 161L, 251L, 171L, 206L, 171L, 
171L, 235L, 161L, 145L, 245L, 183L, 214L, 180L, 220L, 237L, 254L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 153L, 183L, 261L, 245L, 235L, 200L, 246L, 
174L, 180L, 319L, 146L, 251L, 230L, 290L, 230L, 233L, 250L, 255L, 
233L, 175L, 230L, 180L, 145L, 185L, 196L, 298L, 183L, 198L, 195L, 
300L, 270L, 297L, 225L, 212L, 195L, 197L, 146L, 296L), Range = c(400L, 
402L, 500L, 500L, 400L, 350L, 402L, 700L, 525L, 300L, 560L, 550L, 
250L, 450L, 700L, 600L, 175L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 600L, 800L, 500L, 
600L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 400L, 250L, 400L, 350L, 547L, 450L, 1770L, 
800L, 2365L, 925L, 400L, 1205L, 580L, 600L, 600L, 684L, 402L, 
563L, 644L, 885L, 885L, 800L, 440L, 557L, 750L, 3600L, 500L, 
805L, 330L, 600L, 628L, 1640L, 1640L, 1640L, 1640L, 604L, 1046L, 
644L, 500L, 600L, 1046L, 550L, 1585L, 650L, 917L, 515L, 805L, 
750L, 1110L, 772L, 1127L, 500L, 850L, 523L, 850L, 900L, 700L, 
668L, 700L, 1706L, 600L, 1385L, 1000L, 902L, 600L, 500L, 450L, 
579L, 1125L, 1300L, 660L, 515L, 756L)), row.names = c(NA, 100L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that I do not have access to your aircraft.csv, nor did you mention which lda function you used, I did something for iris using `MASS:lda`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

lda.0 = lda( Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris )
preds.0 = predict( lda.0 )$class
xtabs( ~ preds.0 + iris$Species )
str(predict( lda.0 ))
lda.0$means
```

With the last call, you get the means of the classes.

You van calculate the means of the **assigned** classes by working with the data.frame "classified" from your example:

```
classified %>% group_by(assigned) %>% summarize(meanSL=mean(Sepal.Length),meanSW=mean(Sepal.Width), meanPL=mean(Petal.Length), meanPW=mean(Petal.Width))
```

Comment: You can also inspect R objects either in RStudio or by looking at what is returned after the $ sign, e.g. lda.0$prior. This lda.0 list has 10 objects it can return directly with $.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed `MASS:lda`. Thanks, I didn't realise I could just do `lda.0$means`. But what about for the Fisher's LDA example (the large code chunk example)?

Comment: Ahh, yes, that looks about right. This is what I've adapted it into: `classified %>% group_by(assigned) %>% summarize(meanLength = mean(classified$Length), meanWeight = mean(classified$Weight), meanPower = mean(classified$Power), meanSpan = mean(classified$Span), meanSpeed = mean(classified$Speed), meanRange = mean(classified$Range))` Does that look correct to you?